# How is the nested child added process?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var threadRef = rootRef.child("Forum").child(QueryString.courseCode).child(QueryString.Forum).child("Thread");
threadRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var studref = rootRef.child("Student").child(snap.val().replyby);
    alert('outer');
    studref.once("value", snapshot => {
        alert('inner');
    });
});
```

Recent result

```
outer
outer
inner
inner
```

How can I make the output become like below?

```
outer
inner
outer
inner
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't, at least not without orchestrating this yourself. Data is delivered as it is delivered "on the wire", and decoded from there. This is a non-deterministic process primarily dictated by when the data arrives from the server.

If you really needed this to be delivered in-order as a final tree, I would store it as a tree as the data arrives, but not display it. Execute a callback once all the data has arrived, and then you can process your data in any order you wish. It is not efficient, but fairly easy to code.